# Why do the sys.stdout.encoding differ when output is piped (in Python2.x)?

Tags: python, python-2.x

When I run the same code with different piping, why output is different?

```
% python2.7  -c 'import sys; print sys.stdout.encoding'
UTF-8
% python2.7  -c 'import sys; print sys.stdout.encoding' | cat
None
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because when you use `cat` (or any pipe), you unbind the process from terminal. Python derives information about encoding from terminal settings.

You can force the encoding using enironment variable:

```
export PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8
```